# How can I find the nth substring in between two substrings in C?

Tags: c, string, substring, instance

I'm using this function to get a substring in between two substrings.

```
char * extract_between(const char *str, const char *p1, const char *p2/*, const int instance*/)
{
   //int count;
   const char *i1 = strstr(str, p1);
   /*for (count = 0; ; ++count) {
        const char *i1 = strstr(str, p1);
        if (count==instance)
            break;
   }*/
   if(i1 != NULL)
   {
      const size_t pl1 = strlen(p1);
      const char *i2 = strstr(i1 + pl1, p2);
      if(p2 != NULL)
      {
         /* Found both markers, extract text. */
         const size_t mlen = i2 - (i1 + pl1);
         char *ret = malloc(mlen + 1);
         if(ret != NULL)
         {
            memcpy(ret, i1 + pl1, mlen);
            ret[mlen] = '\0';
            return ret;
         }
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I want to modify this so that it will search for the nth instance of the sub-substring, per se. How is this possible? I've tried a for(count) but im not sure how to format it.

Comment: Please post some examples to add clarity to your goal.

Comment: since `strstr` locates the first occurrence, you will have to use `strstr` to locate the first pointer, then chop the source string to start at that location, then do the `strstr` again with the new, shorter string, and repeat `instance` number of times.

Comment: as an aside, this function might be a good candidate for being recursive; passing the shorter string and the `instance-1` to itself each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char*
extract_between (const char* str, const char* p1, const char* p2, int instance)
{
  int count = -1;
  const char* i1 = str - 1;
  for (; count < instance; ++count) {
        i1 = strstr(i1 + 1, p1);
        if (i1 == NULL)
            return NULL;
  }
  const size_t pl1 = strlen(p1);
  const char* i2 = strstr(i1 + pl1, p2);
  if (i2 != NULL)
  {
    /* Found both markers, extract text. */
    const size_t mlen = i2 - (i1 + pl1);
    char* ret = malloc(mlen + 1);
    if (ret != NULL)
    {
      memcpy(ret, i1 + pl1, mlen);
      ret[mlen] = '\0';
      return ret;
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Sample runs:

```
extract_between("foobarbaz", "foo", "bar", 0) = ""
extract_between("foobarbaz", "foo", "bar", 1) = NULL
extract_between("foobarbaz", "foo", "baz", 0) = "bar"
extract_between("foobarfoobarbaz", "foo", "bar", 1) = ""
extract_between("foobarfoobarbaz", "foo", "baz", 1) = "bar"
extract_between("foofoofoobarfoo", "foo", "bar", 2) = ""
extract_between("foofoofoobarfoo", "foo", "foo", 2) = "bar"
extract_between("foofoofoobarfoo", "foo", "bar", 3) = NULL
```

Comment: Replacing your `break` with `return NULL;` eliminates the remaining unnecessary tests to get to `return NULL;`. While legal in use, `const char* i1 = str - 1;` will invoked *Undefined Behavior* if `i1` is ever referenced before the pointer address is incremented.

Comment: Good points, thanks! I removed the unnecessary tests as you suggested. I'm not sure what to do about `i1` being a ticking bomb for two lines, tho.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "ticking bomb" for i1, but the code works great, thanks!

Comment: Oh, it’s just that i1, after being decremented, must not be dereferenced until it is incremented again. The code is fine, it’s more of a maintainability remark.

Comment: ah, ok. thanks for clearing that up. Uh, this'll probably sound like a noob question but when I do `if (extract_between(<variables>) == "foo") {}` it gives me an error about comparing a literal string. What might this be? I'm still rough with C

Comment: I get: "Result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead)" here, which is expected. It's only a warning by default with my compiler, but a very important one: the `==` operator here is comparing pointers (the adresses of the string buffers), not their contents, as you surely intended. You should call `strncmp` instead as indicated by the message. Also, be careful: the `extract_between` function can return `NULL`, so you will need to check for that first, before passing its result to any code that expects a valid address.

Comment: Ill look into `strncmp`, thank you! And I already checked for NULL, I could figure out that much, haha.